# Why can't I get into Sculpting Mode with metaballs?

Tags: sculpting

When i start Blender 2.8 i click on "sculpting" and then i get a ball and can start sculpting. I see the brushes etc...

But when i click on "object mode" to add, for example 2 balls for eyes, i can´t get back to sculpting mode.

In the small menu where one can find the different modes, i then only have "object mode" and "edit mode".

Am i missing something? ¯_(ツ)_/¯

EDIT:
Ok. I tried out a little bit and it seems that i can´t go back to sculpting mode if i add a "metaball".
When adding a Mesh - UV Ball i can go to sculpting mode again.

I don´t quite understand the difference yet, but i think that was the problem :]

Comment: Read this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/metas/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Metaballs need to be converted to mesh before returning to sculpt mode.
Object > Convert to > Mesh from Meta/etc